# How to make queue(delay) for methods?

Tags: c#

I have placed two methods in my Form1_load method and when my form is loaded, method `private void get()` doesn't get `webBrowser1.DocumentTitle`, it's empty, but the webpage is loaded.

How can I make a queue or delay to run `get()`, after `url()` is loaded?
if I assign `get()` to some button, the code runs ok.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        url();
        get();
    }


    private void url()
    {
        string url = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4908966&scope=notify,friends,photos,audio,video,status,wall,groups,messages,stats&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token";
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
    }
    private void get()
    {
        if (webBrowser1.DocumentTitle == "OAuth Blank")
        {
            string get_string_url = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
            string split = get_string_url.Split('&')[0];
            string split2 = split.Split('=')[1];
            textBox1.Text = split2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's entirely normal, the browser needs time to finish loading the page.  You must write an event handler for the DocumentCompleted event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DocumentCompleted` or `Navigated` events like this.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (_s, _e) =>
    {
        // do something with DocumentTitle
        this.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentTitle;
    };
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168674/how-to-make-queuedelay-for-methods");
}
```